# API call not reaching Vite proxy target (localhost:5000)

Tags: docker, proxy, vuejs3, vite, json-server

So I'm trying to learn Vue and I've set up a project and a json-server backend, both running with Docker. Almost everything is working as intended.
I've written a function to fetch the tasks in the json backend:

```js
async fetchTasks(){
    const res = await fetch('api/tasks')
    const data = await res.json()
    return data
}
```

When I try to fetch the tasks:

```js
async created(){
    this.tasks = await this.fetchTasks()
}
```

I get the following error on the browser console:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/api/tasks 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I also get this on the terminal running the container:

```shellscript
task-tracker     | 6:46:11 PM [vite] http proxy error:
task-tracker     | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5000
task-tracker     |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1278:16)
```

**But if I change the funtion to:**

```js
async fetchTasks(){
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/tasks') //hardcoded localhost
    const data = await res.json()
    return data
}
```

**everything works fine.**

**Manually accessing localhost:5000/tasks using the browser also works.** It shows the contents of db.json.

**Changing *target* to *jsonplaceholder.typicode.com* also works** but it's not the data I want.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my vite config:

```js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue()],
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
      }
    },
    server: {
      proxy: {
        '/api': {
          target: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000',
          changeOrigin: true,
          secure: false,
          rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, '')
        }
      }
    }
})
```

db.json (backend):

```js
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "text": "Doctors appointment",
            "day": "March 1st at 2:30 pm",
            "reminder": true
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "text": "Meeting at school",
            "day": "March 3rd at 1:30 pm",
            "reminder": true
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "text": "Food Shopping",
            "day": "March 3rd at 11:00 am pm",
            "reminder": false
        }
    ]
}
```

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
services:
    task-tracker:
      image: "node:16"
      container_name: "task-tracker"
      user: "node"
      working_dir: "/usr/src/app"
      environment:
        - NODE_ENV=development
      volumes:
        - ./:/usr/src/app
      ports:
        - "8080:8080"
      command: "npm run dev -- --port 8080"
    task-tracker-db:
      image: "clue/json-server" #https://github.com/clue/docker-json-server
      container_name: "task-tracker-db"
      working_dir: "/data"
      environment:
        - NODE_ENV=development
      volumes:
        - ./db:/data
      ports:
        - "5000:80" #has to be 80 because the image exposes port 80
```

I tried:

- Following [the documentation](https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-proxy).
- Setting the *ws* option to *true*.
- Configuring with the following code:

```js
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy: {
            '^/api': {
                target: 'http://localhost:5000',
                changeOrigin: true,
                logLevel: 'debug',
                pathRewrite: {'^/api': '/'}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Changing *server* to *devServer*
- Using RegEx
- Changing the *task-tracker-db* host port in *docker-compose.yml*
- Changing *127.0.0.1:5000* to *localhost:5000*

Answer (score 1):

When you spin up your Docker container with `docker compose`, a [network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) will be created for you, and you can refer to the different services by name as long as you are inside the network.

The reason you can access `http://localhost:5000` through the browser is that you exposed port `5000` to the outside of the container when you defined:

```yaml
services:
    ...
    task-tracker-db:
      ...
      ports:
        - "5000:80"
```

But since you're trying to access the service from **inside** the container, you need to use the following syntax:

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy: {
            '^/api': {
                target: 'http://task-tracker-db:80', // see here
                changeOrigin: true,
                logLevel: 'debug',
                pathRewrite: {'^/api': '/'}
            }
        }
    }
}
```